# Como passar um vector como parâmetro de uma função em C++?

Tags: c++

Estou declarando esse vector e quero passar ele como parâmetro de uma função, como faço?

```
vector<string> matriz_ambiente;

    arquivo.open("teste.txt");

    if (arquivo.is_open()){
        while(getline(arquivo, linha)){
            matriz_ambiente.push_back(linha);
            cout << linha << endl;
        }
```

Função:

```
void geracao(string matriz_ambiente){
```

Answer (score 1):

O modo usual de passar variáveis "grandes" em C++ é por referência:

```
// declaracao do vetor de strings
vector<string> matriz_ambiente;
...
...
// declaracao da funcao
void geracao(vector<string>& parm_matriz_ambiente)
{
  ...
  ...
}
...
// chamada da função
geracao(matriz_ambiente);
....
```